# Get max of 2 objects

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++. Is there a way I could compare 2 objects of the same class and return the bigger one?

This is some pseudo code to illustrate the idea

```
HashMap biggerObject = std::max( obj1, obj2,
                             []( HashMap &a, HashMap &b )
                             {
                                 return a.size() < b.size();
                             } );
```

And how could I write HashMap in a way so that it knows how to compare itself?

Comment: Normally comparable containers already provide a `operator<` that makes sense.

Comment: I have implemented HashMap myself. So there is no comparable operator implemented at the moment

Comment: If you define the operator you should be aligned with what `max` expects.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/operator_overloading

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
HashMap biggerObject = std::max(obj1, obj2,
                                    [](const HashMap &a, const HashMap &b) {
                                        return a.size() < b.size();
                                    });
```

You can also overload the operator of your own `class`: Here's a simple example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct HashMap {
    int value = 10;
    std::string whatever;

    bool operator<(const HashMap &rhs) const {
        // your logics..
        return value < rhs.value;
    }
};

int main() {

    HashMap map1, map2;
    map1.value = 100;
    map2.value = 10;

    const auto &val = std::max(map1, map2);

    std::cout << val.value << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while it is easy to add an `operator<` method to your own implementation of HashMap, is this the **only** meaning of less-than for the HashMap container? If not, then it will cause confusion in the future. Could less-than also mean subset-of?

It may be better to write a generic function that relies on the class having a size() member that it compares, or even just a simple function that takes 2 of your HashMap objects:

```
template <class Container>
Container& FewestMembers(Container& lhs, Container& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.size() < rhs.size())
        return lhs;
    else
        return rhs;
}

template <class Container>
Container& MostMembers(Container& lhs, Container& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.size() > rhs.size())
        return lhs;
    else
        return rhs;
}
```

Comment: good point with "subset" have not thought about it. How would you call FewestMembers with max?

Comment: @Chris you wouldn't use `std::max` here, you'd just use `HashMap& biggerObj = MostMembers(obj1, obj2);`. Assuming a similar implementation of `MostMembers` as `FewestMembers`.